# Is it more accurate to describe the behaviour of the async attribute as moving a script tag to the macro-task queue as soon it's loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

When a script has the `async` attribute, it's described as: 'it executes as soon as it's loaded'.

Imagine the browser is initially loading the page. It comes across a script tag (let's call it script tag 1) with the `async` attribute. Therefore, it begins loading it. It then moves onto another (regular) script tag (let's call it script tag 2). Script tag 2 loads and begins executing. While script tag 2 is executing, script tag 1 has finished loading. Surely script tag 1 only executes when script tag 2 has finished executing (i.e. is off the main-stack).

Is it more accurate to describe the behaviour of the async attribute as moving a script tag to the macro-task queue as soon it's loaded?

Comment: bad reasoning. when we talk about synchronization we are talking about two or more elements. if any of them is "async" for a script then that means it doesn't care about other parts of the HTML to perform its tasks.

Comment: @user2864740 What does remove all ordering between two scripts mean?

Comment: Thanks for the response @user2864740. How is this answering my question though?

Comment: Thanks for the response @MisterJojo. Would you mind putting it in the context of the example I give in my question?

Comment: Sorry @user2864740 I'm not following how this relates to the example in my question. Do async scripts get put in the macro-task queue? And if not, how are they executed when another script is already being processed in the call-stack?

Comment: your context is unclear. in javascript the task queue is used to start processes, this means that the tasks are launched in a queue without worrying about knowing if the previous task is finished and may working concurrently

Comment: @MisterJojo Sorry I think I've made it a bit more clear. I think it'll make sense if you look at it now. In short, I suspect async script 1 can't execute whilst script 2 is executing so perhaps when script 1 is loaded it gets put in the task queue (in case something is already executing in the call-stack)

Comment: "*'it executes as soon as it's loaded*" implicitly means that it's scheduled to as a macro task to execute, like everything else in javascript. The `async` attribute is described as so to distinguish it from synchronously loading and executing scripts. Like everything else, it's a simplification - we omit details that are irrelevant in the current context.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I wanted to make sure although named something like 'async' I can see how it looks obvious too.

Comment: no, your async scripts 1 and 2 can be executed at the same time, whatever their order of launch. the duration of their execution does not enter into the equation.